# Python take specific set of caracters on a string

Tags: python, string, formatting

how are you doing?

So I need to take a part of a string using python.

Like this example:

I have this string: *"hey I'm using python now"* and I want to take only the part between the *"hey"* and *"now"* so the output would be just *"I'm using python"*.
I know how to do this with string slicing. but how could I do this based on the flags *"hey"* and *"now"* and take everything in the middle.

How could I accomplish that?

Comment: The rule you're trying to apply isn't very clear. Do you want everything after the first `'hey'`, or after the last one, or after the last one before a `now`, or…? Do you want to only count `'hey '` as a marker, or `'hey'` with 0 or more optional whitespace characters? And so on.

Comment: Once you decide on a rule, it's very easy to implement in terms of `s.split('hey')` and `s.split('now')`, or maybe `rsplit` or `partition` instead, and maybe a `strip` call or two. Or to write it as a regex, with or without greedy matching. But until you have a specific rule you want, you can't write anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `regex`:

```
import re
s = "hey I'm using python now" 
result = re.findall(r'hey (.*) now', s)
print(''.join(result))

# I'm using python
```

Comment: If you use `sub`, then you don't have to join the result. Something like `re.sub(r"\bhey|now\b",'',s).strip()`